CRM Analytics External Data API Limit
I am currently working with CRM Analytics. I need a little bit of help with understanding the External Data API Limit.
As we can read in the documentation the Maximum number of external data jobs per dataset that can be run in a rolling 24-hour period is equal 50.
Questions

What does it exactly mean? Can I run a maximum of 50 recipes per 24 hours?
Is there a way to get that limit in Apex or LWC? I've found that Analytics limits endpoint, but there is no limit like that.


